# HTML Issue, strange characters replacing HREF quotes

Tags: html, unicode, href

I am new to HTML coding. I'm taking an intro web design course this semester and i'm having a difficult time with my HREF segment. I have a table of contents page that references all of my projects over the semester.

This includes direct links to my projects where I should be able to embed my index.html file with the links to my new projects. However, whenever I try to update the HREF segments with quotes linking to my new project it spits out odd characters where the quotes would be.

Ã¢â‚ example of what the error shows below.

```
**The requested URL /Ã¢â‚¬Å“http://userid.myweb.usf.edu/project1/index.htmlÃ¢â‚¬Å“ was not found on this server.**


<li>This link goes to <a href=“http://userid.myweb.usf.edu/project1/index.html“>Project1</a></li>
```

I see a lot of references to it being a UNICODE8 issue but i have no idea what that means. If anyone could help i would greatly appreciate it as my professor is not the best at getting back to us.

Comment: You need to give a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue so that we can help you. Edit your question accordingly. Next time, read the guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow before posting.

Comment: What software are you using to write the HTML?

Comment: I am using TextEdit for mac

Comment: You need to var dump or console.log the variables your using to modify the link href attribute. If using chrome, make sure dev tools is enable and hard refresh the page.

Comment: @btk666 — TextEdit is a *word processor* and not a text editor (the name doesn't help). This is probably the cause of your problems. Get a text editor. VS Code is free and popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag is using `“` quote characters (Unicode codepoint `U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`).  HTML requires `"` quote characters instead (codepoint `U+0022 QUOTATION MARK`).

```html
<li>This link goes to <a href="http://userid.myweb.usf.edu/project1/index.html">Project1</a></li>
```

Some editors, particularly word processors that were designed for editing documents and not HTML, will use `“` instead of `"` when you type <kbd>"</kbd> on the keyboard or copy/paste text from other apps, so watch out for that.  Use a text editor that is specifically designed for editing HTML, or at least a plain vanilla text editor, like NotePad/NodePad++, which doesn't reinterpret entered characters.

---

Here is a breakdown of what `Ã¢â‚¬Å“` means:

The Unicode `“` (U+201C) character, which you are entering in your HTML, is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `E2 80 9C`.

When those same bytes are interpreted in the Windows-1252 charset (the default charset used by most Windows systems in Western countries), byte `E2` is Unicode codepoint U+00E2 (`â`), byte `80` is codepoint U+20AC (`€`), and byte `9C` is codepoint U+0153 (`œ`).

When encoded in UTF-8, codepoint U+00E2 is bytes `C3 A2`, codepoint U+20AC is bytes `E2 82 AC`, and codepoint U+0153 is bytes `C5 93`.

In Windows-1252, characters `Ã¢â‚¬Å“` are bytes `C3 A2` `E2 82 AC` `C5 93`.

Look familiar?

You have a charset mismatch between what you are saving your HTML file as, and what your web browser is interpreting the HTML as. Your HTML is being saved as UTF-8, but is being decoded to Unicode mis-interpretted as Windows-1252 instead of as UTF-8, re-encoded as UTF-8, and then displayed as Windows-1252.

If you are serving your HTML file over HTTP, make sure the HTTP server is reporting the correct `charset=UTF-8` attribute in the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

You can (and should) also add a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` tag (if using HTML4) or `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag (if using HTML5) to your HTML itself (when served over HTTP, web browsers are required to give the actual `Content-Type` HTTP header higher priority, though).

Make sure the reported `charset` in all cases matches the actual charset that you are saving your HTML file as.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked, and the explanation of the error and detail on what the characters represent was just going the extra mile. Thank you again so much for taking the time to break it all down for me.